# Yii - Query Manipulation for Custom CGridView with Advanced Search

Tags: php, mysql, yii

So, I've extended [CGridView](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CGridView) to include an Advanced Search feature tailored to the needs of my organization.

- **Filter** - lets you show/hide columns in the table, and you can also reorder columns by dragging the little drag icon to the left of each item.
- **Sort** - Allows for the selection of multiple columns, specify Ascending or Descending.
- **Search** - Select your column and insert search parameters. Operators tailored to data type of selected column.

[image: Advanced Search Screenshot]

Version 1 works, albeit slowly. Basically, I had my hands in the inner workings of [CGridView](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CGridView), where I snatch the results from the [DataProvider](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveDataProvider) and do the searching and sorting in PHP before rendering the table contents.

Now writing Version 2, where I aim to focus on clever [CDbCriteria](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCriteria) creation, allowing MySQL to do the heavy lifting so it will run quicker. The implementation is trivial when dealing with a single database table. The difficulty arises when I'm dealing with 2 or more tables... For example, if the user intends to search on a field that is a [STAT](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.arr#statistical-query) relation, I need that relation to be present in my query so that I may include comparisons.

**Here's the question. How do I assure that Yii includes all `with` relations in my query so that I include comparisons?** I've included all my relations `with` my criteria in the model's `search` function and I've tried CDbCriteria's `together` set to true ...

```
public function search() {
    $criteria=new CDbCriteria;
    $criteria->compare('id', $this->id);
    $criteria->compare( ...
    ...
    $criteria->with = array('relation0','relation1','relation3');
    $criteria->together = true;

    return new CActiveDataProvider(
        get_class($this), array(
            'criteria'=>$criteria,
            'pagination' => array('pageSize' => 50)
));}
```

Then I'll snatch the criteria from the [DataProvider](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveDataProvider) and [add a few conditions](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCriteria#addCondition-detail), for example, looking for dates > 1234567890. But I still get errors like this...

```
CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: 
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 't.relation3' in 'where clause'. 
The SQL statement executed was: 
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT `t`.`id`) FROM `table` `t` 
LEFT OUTER JOIN `relation_table` `relation0` ON (`t`.`id`=`relation0`.`id`) 
LEFT OUTER JOIN `relation_table` `relation1` ON (`t`.`id`=`relation1`.`id`) 
WHERE (`t`.`relation3` > 1234567890)
```

Where `relation0` and `relation1` are `BELONGS_TO` relations, but any `STAT` relations, here depicted as `relation3`, are missing. Furthermore, why is the query a `SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT 't'.'id')` ?

**Edit** @DCoder Here's the specific relation I'm working with now. The main table is Call, which has a [`HAS_MANY`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.arr#declaring-relationship) relation to CallSegments, which keeps the times. So the `startTime` of the Call is the minimum start_time of all the related CallSegments. And `startTime` is the hypothetical `relation3` in my anonymized query error.

```
'startTime' => array(self::STAT, 'CallSegments', 'call_id',
            'select' => 'min(`start_time`)'),
```

**Edit** Other people have sent me to [CDbCriteria's `together` property](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCriteria#together-detail), but as you can see above, I am currently trying that to no avail.

**Edit** Looks like the issue <strike>has</strike> may have been reported: [Yii](http://code.google.com/p/yii/issues/detail?id=2494) and [github](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/issues/204) tickets.

Comment: Can you show more related code, specifically the model's relation declarations? STAT relations are usually executed as separate queries.

Comment: Alright @DCoder , I've added the relation I'm working with now. Do you want more? Any way to include the STAT relation in the query? I thought that's what CDbCriteria's together was for, but apparently not.

Comment: It's still not clear to me what your anonymized relation0, relation1 and relation3 are, but I think that you will need to select call_id and min(start_time) into a temp table and join into that table instead of relying on STAT. If your database engine supports computed columns, that can be a decent alternative.

Comment: @DCoder Hmm... I'm not thrilled with your answer. Not that it's wrong, just that it would be a mess to implement. I've updated the post with a little more information about the relations. But basically, you don't think Yii supports a way to include all specified relational JOINs in the same query?

Comment: As I see it, STAT is a special relation case because it requires aggregation, whereas other relations are simple matches. It would seem that Yii queries STATs in a separate query instead of joining a temp table to the main query body.

In my opinion, the issue you linked to is not exactly the same problem as you're having.

Comment: After looking at the framework code more closely, I'm afraid I have to stand by my original remarks - the framework code always runs STAT relations in separate queries and the only way to get the behaviour you want is to patch CActiveRecord and CActiveFinder. I started a patch to make them behave better, but it's apparently not a one-hour project, and I don't have enough familiarity with these internals to make it fully functional. You can find the work I've done thus far at https://github.com/DCoderLT/yii/tree/ar-stat-together .

Comment: Wow, thank you. You have certainly gone above and beyond the call of duty here. Thank you so much for your time and effort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not a good idea to snatch the sql from a criteria and use it by yourself.

If you are using the "with" property then you could easily use comparisons like:

```
$criteria->compare("`relation1`.`id`", $yourVarHere);
```

Also Yii doesn't behave well with grouping.

My approach with STAT relations is using an subquery in the selects of Yii, followed by having:

```
$criteria->select = array("`t`.*", "(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `relation3` WHERE `id` = `t`.id_relation3) AS `rel3`");
$criteria->having = "`rel3` > " . $yourValue;
```

The above method creates a bug in the gridview pagination because the count is done on a different query. A workaround will be to drop the "with" property and write the joins by yourself in the "join" property like:

```
$criteria->join = "LEFT OUTER JOIN `relation_table` `relation0` ON (`t`.`id`=`relation0`.`id`) 
LEFT OUTER JOIN `relation_table` `relation1` ON (`t`.`id`=`relation1`.`id`)
LEFT OUTER JOIN `relation_table` `relation3` ON (`t`.`id`=`relation3`.`id`)";
```

Answer (score 0):

If the bug is a little difficult to get working could you use the stat relation as a simple HAS_ONE with :

```
'select'=>'count(relation3.id)', 
'joinType'=>'left join',
'group'=>'relation3.id',
'on'=>'t.id = relation3.id',
'together'=>true
```

to get the count value out along side everything else?

Not sure how well this would work for your case but it's been helpful for me from time to time.